# Connect to sql server windows authentication

Tags: java, sql-server

I have a sql server instance ,

I can connect with sql autehntication

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Connection conn = null;
     String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
     String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;databasename=Test;";
     String userName = "sa"; 
     String password = "paquito";
     Statement stmt;
     try{
       Class.forName(driver);//.newInstance();
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
       stmt = conn.createStatement();
       System.out.println("conectado = "); 
       conn.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

but with windows authentication

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Connection conn = null;
     String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
     String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;databasename=Test;integratedSecurity=true";
     String userName = "paco"; 
     String password = "";
     Statement stmt;
     try{
       Class.forName(driver);//.newInstance();
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
       stmt = conn.createStatement();
       System.out.println("conectado = "); 
       conn.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

i take this error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Unable to open the "Test" database requested by the login. Login failed. Client connection ID: 577da72f-f0d4-4ac6-abab-243f0f84d0e3
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:279)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:99)
```

NOTE: in sql management i can connect with sql authentication and windows authentication

suggestion?

Comment: Can you translate the error message into English?

Comment: sorry, i modified error

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace integratedSecurity with Integrated Security in your connection string and try this?

Comment: if i modify this: 
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;databasename=Test;integratedSecurity=true;username=paco";
i take same error

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify a username, it will get this from the current user.

See https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ for more details.

Comment: i need specify username, because later i converto java application in web application and maybe user actually dont have permissions in sql server instance

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that.  You either specify integratedSecurity=true or give a username and password.  If you specify both how's the driver supposed to know what to do?